# Php Regex Expression

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex expression:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', function

($matches){return en($matches[1]);}, $str);
```

Against this html code:

```
<iframe src="//example.com/hello.php"></iframe>
```

the output is:

```
 <iframe src="//maskedurl.php?l=kdsdhkhdkshdkhsdskhd"></iframe>
```

How can i have the regex not output the 2 slashes, `//` ? and have it only display:

```
<iframe src="maskedurl.php?l=kdsdhkhdkshdkhsdskhd"></iframe>
```

yes I know it's missing the http: but that is out of my control

Comment: Expect regex not ideal for HTML parsing admonishments.

Comment: even then, this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aA5vB1/1) shows that your group is capturing that you expect to capture.

Comment: @dustmouse He's not using the regexp to parse HTML, he's using it to parse a URL.

Comment: 2 options: (re)move the outer brackets, because there `//` is being grouped, which you don't want. Alternatively: return a `substr` from within the callback (ie `substr($matches[1], 2)`)

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify the `(https?://)` part, so that it accepts also the `//`. This could result in something easy as `((?:https?:)?//)` or `(https?://|//)`

So in the end you have the following regex

```
'@((https?://|//)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@'
```

php

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('@((https?://|//)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', function ($matches){return en($matches[0]);}, $str);
```

Comment: OP isn't worried about the `http(s)` not being there, he's worried about the callback returning the first two characters (ie `//`)

Comment: Then he should use `$matches[0]`

Comment: No, read the question carefully: he **doesn't** want to return the first two chars: he needs to either _not_ capture the first part of the match, or return `substr($match[1], 2);`

Comment: His problem is, he want to mask the url, but the first two // are ignored and never get replaces by his regex. So he would also the first two // in his regex. If the protocol should be ignored, he could/have to do this in his callback function.